# How can get request daterangepicker_start, daterangepicker_end in daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker, daterangepicker

I use daterange picker and I try to send daterangepicker_start and daterangepicker_end but I cant because of daterangepicker_start,daterangepicker_end are not in form

how to send start and end in form

here is my js

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".input-daterange-datepicker").daterangepicker({
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY/DD/MM'
                },
            });
        });

    </script>
```

here is my balde template

```
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['user-mangement.index'],'class' => 'form-material text-right col-6 p-r-20']) !!}
    {{ Form::text('daterange',null,['placeholder' => 'ss' ,'class' => 'form-control input-daterange-datepicker col-6' ]) }}
    {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-inverse waves-effect waves-light m-r-15'] )  }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

in my controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $s = $request->input('s');
        $daterange = $request->input('daterange');
        $users = User::sortable(['created_at' => 'desc'])->search($s)->paginate(10);
        return view('backend/user/index',compact('users'));
    }
```

How can I get request from daterangepicker_stard and daterangepicker_end Just Now I can get only request from daterange  ex 2018-1-1 - 2018-2-2
I Know I can implode them but is there anyway to get request 2018-1-1  and request 2018-2-2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:I hope it will help you.

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

Comment: now , i can create input type hidden and set value  $( "#date_start" ).val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); in my form